# Inserting Data from JSON Call into Page

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I’m trying to read a piece of data from a JSON call and display it on a page. The JSON data is at the following URL:

https://slides.tap5050.com/slidesJackpotLoader.php?EID=223

Specifically, I want to display the field “jackpotInt” on one of my Wordpress pages. The code I’m trying to use is as follows:

```
<div id="jackpotTotal"></div>
<script>
    fetch('https://slides.tap5050.com/slidesJackpotLoader.php?EID=223')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            window.alert('error: ' + err);
        });
    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("jackpotTotal");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = data[i].jackpotInt;
            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, nothing is being output on the page. I added the window.alert to see if any errors were being thrown, but I’m not receiving any error messages. My experience with JSON is limited, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have a typo in `mmainContainer.appendChild(div);` your variable is called `mainContainer`

Also the URL is returning an object and not an array, I don't know if you are using the same data source, if its the case, you won't need the loop

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo, unfortunately I’m still not seeing any data on the page. I see what you mean about the loop, could having the loop be the problem?

Comment: You might want to consider not using `innerHTML`...maybe `div.textContent = data[i].jackpotInt` instead. Inserting as HTML something received from an outside source leaves you open to injection attacks. For example, what if someone hacks tap5050.com so that `jackpotInt` is a string containing a script tag? or a style tag? or a base tag? Could do bad things to your site.

Comment: I think the loop is the problem, here's a code example 
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-minsky-cmc8w?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response object. so, it's not looping.

**Try Using:**

```js
fetch("https://slides.tap5050.com/slidesJackpotLoader.php?EID=223")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    appendData(data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    window.alert("error: " + err);
  });

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("jackpotTotal");
  if (typeof data == 'object') {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(item => {
      if (item == "jackpotInt") {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = data.jackpotInt;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
      }
    });
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = data[i].jackpotInt;
      mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="jackpotTotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON data is not and `Array`, it is an `Object`, to get  the `jackpotInt` property value, just call `data["jackpotInt"]`:

```
  function appendData(data) {
      const mainContainer = document.getElementById("jackpotTotal");
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = data["jackpotInt"];
      mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  }
```